# If Hataras nedarim on erev R'H voids all future vows, commitments, then is it even possible to make a vow or commitment?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

Based on the text of Hataras Nedarim, specifically, "...I nullify from now on all the vows, all the oaths, prohibitions, assents and commitments in thought which I will take upon myself...and if I should forget the stipulations of this declaration and make further vows henceforth, from now on I regret them and declare that they are all null and void..." (Siddur Tehilas Hashem, English translation), is it possible to make a vow or is every vow voided from the outset because of this declaration?

It would seems that we preemptively void any future vows or commitments.

Comment: We do avoid vows at all costs, really. That's why we say "bli neder" when we "promise".

Comment: If you explicitly intend the vow to count in spite of that declaration then it definitely still takes effect.